# Creating a DataFrame with Correlations for 2 variables in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby, correlation

I currently have a pandas dataframe that I've done a lot of manipulation on which has the % daily change of a coin and the % change in twitter sentiment on a daily basis. The dataframe looks like the below:

```
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|            | % Change in Price | % Change in Sentiment |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| 2019-01-31 |             12.4% |                   10% |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| 2019-02-01 |              115% |                   84% |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| 2019-02-02 |               62% |                   33% |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| 2019-02-03 |               14% |                  -15% |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| ...        | ...               | ...                   |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| 2021-06-29 | 12%               | 72%                   |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| 2021-06-30 | 18%               | 62%                   |
+------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new data frame that calculates a monthly correlation between the two columns % Change in Price and % Change in Sentiment with the end output being something like the below:

```
+------------+-------------+
|            | Correlation |
+------------+-------------+
| 2019-01-01 |         .43 |
+------------+-------------+
| 2019-02-01 |         .15 |
+------------+-------------+
| 2019-03-01 |         .09 |
+------------+-------------+
| 2019-04-01 |         .35 |
+------------+-------------+
| ...        | ...         |
+------------+-------------+
| 2021-05-01 | -.88        |
+------------+-------------+
| 2021-06-01 | -.12        |
+------------+-------------+
```

Thanks for any support on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the [Pearson Correlation Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient):

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).corr().iloc[0::2,-1].droplevel(1)`

**Explanation**

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))` → group by month

`.corr()` → apply PCC (by default, others available) to get a 2x2 matrix for each month

Easy so far. Next two steps are the fiddly / ugly parts:

`.iloc[0::2,-1]` → pull out the first element of each matrix (which is the only interesting variable in each matrix)

`.droplevel(1)` → we were left with a multiindex that we don't need, so drop the second part

Maybe there is a slightly cleaner way without the last two steps...

Comment: thanks for breaking this down. When I try to implement, I receive an error "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'" I've converted the "new_date" column from string to date/time and also set it as the index, but this does not seem to fix the error. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're welcome. Well, it sounds like your index isn't a DatetimeIndex, it's an Int index. :-)

Can you check the type of the index? `df.index` should be enough. Perhaps you're setting it as a Unix time by mistake. I think `pd.to_datetime(series)` should return the correct type.

Comment: Hi @J.Smith, if you find my answer helpful I would appreciate it if you marked it as the accepted answer :-)